# Getting logically-corresponding records where no direct association exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table logging requests and responses for cases, and the times each occurs. My problem is that there is no direct association between a particular response and the request it's responding to. To make matters even more difficult, there might be multiple responses to one request, and the requests and responses aren't always collated - you might have two requests followed by two responses, which means the first response relates to the first request, and the second response relates to the second request. The simplified table below gives examples of each of those situations:

```
Case_Id     Subject     Date
123         Request     2014-12-03 15:48:02
123         Response    2014-12-03 16:01:45
123         Response    2014-12-03 17:32:23
123         Request     2015-04-10 12:12:17
123         Request     2015-04-10 12:13:34
123         Response    2015-04-10 13:31:20
123         Response    2014-04-10 13:37:12
234         Request     2014-12-03 12:12:20
234         Response    2014-12-03 12:20:23
234         Request     2015-03-03 15:09:44
234         Response    2015-03-03 16:23:54
```

What I want to do is find the first Response that corresponds to each Request within a case so that I could calculate the time it took to respond. So the output of this query should be:

```
Case_Id     Request Time            Response Time
123         2014-12-03 15:48:02     2014-12-03 16:01:45
123         2015-04-10 12:12:17     2015-04-10 13:31:20
123         2015-04-10 12:13:34     2015-04-10 13:37:12
234         2014-12-03 12:12:20     2014-12-03 12:20:23
234         2015-03-03 15:09:44     2015-03-03 16:23:54
```

The problem I'm having is with those non-collated examples where I have two (or more) requests followed by two (or more) responses. So far I've got this:

```
Select N1.Case_id, N1.Date AS Request_Date, N2.Date as Response_Date
FROM Notes N1
  JOIN Notes N2
    ON N1.subject = 'Request'
    AND N2.date = (
      SELECT min(date)
      FROM Notes
      WHERE Case_Id = N1.Case_Id
        AND subject = 'Response'
        AND date > N1.date
    )
```

which almost works, but as you can see from the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8888) it fails when you have multiple requests followed by multiple responses - it takes the first response regardless of the fact that it's been "claimed" by a previous request. I've searched around, but I cannot figure out how to make it exclude Responses that have already been joined with previously.

Comment: Can you really have two responses and only one request, as in the first three rows?

Comment: If you have two requests followed by two responses, how do you know that they are one response per request, rather than two responses to the first request and none to the second?

Comment: It's difficult to exclude the "duplicate" responses in one query. but you can store your result in a temp table, delete duplicates entries , and run the queries again. Repeat it until you get all requests matched.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, sometimes the secon response will provide additional info, but I only really care about the time to the first one.

Comment: @aphrael We can assume each request will have a response.

Comment: You might be able to get creative with the `LAG` function, but unfortunately, it is not available until version 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unpleasant, but it seems to work for your data.  I had to fix a small glitch in your data as you have a different value for row #7 in your data to what is shown in your results.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Case_Id INT,
    [Subject] VARCHAR(50),
    [Date] DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Request', '2014-12-03 15:48:02';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Response', '2014-12-03 16:01:45';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Response', '2014-12-03 17:32:23';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Request', '2015-04-10 12:12:17';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Request', '2015-04-10 12:13:34';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Response', '2015-04-10 13:31:20';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 123, 'Response', '2015-04-10 13:37:12';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 234, 'Request', '2014-12-03 12:12:20';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 234, 'Response', '2014-12-03 12:20:23';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 234, 'Request', '2015-03-03 15:09:44';
INSERT INTO @Data SELECT 234, 'Response', '2015-03-03 16:23:54';
WITH RowIds AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Case_Id, [Date]) AS RowId
    FROM
        @Data),
Requests AS (
    SELECT
        Case_Id,
        [Date]
    FROM
        @Data
    WHERE
        [Subject] = 'Request'),
NextResponse AS (
    SELECT
        r.Case_Id,
        r.[Date] AS Request_Time,
        MIN(d.[Date]) AS Response_Time
    FROM
        Requests r
        INNER JOIN @Data d ON d.Case_id = r.Case_id AND d.[Subject] = 'Response' AND d.[Date] > r.[Date]
    GROUP BY
        r.Case_Id,
        r.[Date]),
AssignIds AS (
    SELECT
        nr.*,
        r.RowId
    FROM
        NextResponse nr
        INNER JOIN RowIds r ON r.Case_Id = nr.Case_Id AND r.[Subject] = 'Response' AND r.[Date] = nr.Response_Time),
FindDuplicates AS (
    SELECT
        RowId
    FROM
        AssignIds
    GROUP BY
        RowId
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1),
ApplyDuplicateOffsets AS (
    SELECT
        a.Case_Id,
        a.Request_Time,
        a.Response_Time,
        a.RowId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.RowId ORDER BY a.Response_Time) AS Offset
    FROM
        FindDuplicates fd
        INNER JOIN AssignIds a ON a.RowId = fd.RowId),
FixDuplicates AS (
    SELECT
        a.Case_Id,
        a.Request_Time,
        MIN(CASE WHEN d.RowId IS NULL THEN a.Response_Time ELSE a2.[Date] END) AS Response_Time
    FROM
        AssignIds a
        LEFT JOIN FindDuplicates d ON d.RowId = a.RowId
        LEFT JOIN ApplyDuplicateOffsets o ON o.RowId = a.RowId AND o.Request_Time = a.Request_Time
        LEFT JOIN RowIds a2 ON a2.Case_Id = a.Case_Id AND a2.RowId >= a.RowId + o.Offset - 1
    GROUP BY
        a.Case_Id,
        a.Request_Time)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    FixDuplicates
ORDER BY
    Case_Id,
    Request_Time;
```

Basically this works as follows:

- first I make a list of the data with a unique row id assigned to each row;
- next I perform a simple match, just picking the next response for each request;
- this ends up using the same response for multiple rows so I find where this happens;
- next I create an order for the duplicates, ordered by date, so the first duplicate is assigned 1, then 2, etc.;
- now I can reassign the response dates (assuming each request has it's own response) by picking the original response for the first duplicate, the next available response for the second duplicate, etc.;
- finally I just spew out the results.

Results look like this:

```
Case_Id Request_Time    Response_Time
123 2014-12-03 15:48:02.000 2014-12-03 16:01:45.000
123 2015-04-10 12:12:17.000 2015-04-10 13:31:20.000
123 2015-04-10 12:13:34.000 2015-04-10 13:37:12.000
234 2014-12-03 12:12:20.000 2014-12-03 12:20:23.000
234 2015-03-03 15:09:44.000 2015-03-03 16:23:54.000
```

Is it a good solution?  Not really, I originally thought this would need some form of recursion and maybe that would be a better way to solve the problem?